# Deleting first item of a $_COOKIE array

Tags: php

if I add an item to the $_COOKIE array as such:

```
setcookie("favorites[]", "value",  time()+3600);
```

I can delete any item from the $_COOKIE[favorites] array like this:

```
setcookie("favorites[$deletekey]", "", time()+3600);
```

EXCEPT the first one added so this does not work:

```
setcookie("favorites[0]", "", time()+3600*24);
```

How can I delete the first one and leave others intact?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how arrays work, you'd know that 0 is actually a key.

```
$myarray = array("key" => "value", 1 => "one");
```

`$myarray[0]` does not exist because that key is not defined. Only the elements `$myarray['key']` and `$myarray[1]` exist in this array. You cannot reference `$myarray['key']` as the first item in the array, because 0 is seen as a key for the array and there is no value defined for that key.

You can, however, use [PHP's `array_values()` function](https://www.php.net/array_values) to create an array of the values (it basically removes the keys) and reference them that way, but with cookies I don't see how this would be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

> I can delete any item from the $_COOKIE[favorites] array like this:

No - when the response is sent back to the browser it should overwrite the current value.

If you want to delete an item from the cookies array do this:

```
 unset($_COOKIE['favorites']);
```

If you want to delete a cookie on the browser set the cookie with the same name (and path, and domain) but an expiry date in the past.

There is no such thing as a cookie arry client side - you're confusing PHPs syntax for adding items to an array with how HTTP works. It may be that when the request comes back, PHP will create an array from a cookie named 'favourites[]' but there is no such array on the client - just a single value.

```
setcookie("favorites[]", "value",  time()+3600);
```

creates a cookie named 'favourites[]' which is why its not changed by:

```
setcookie("favorites[0]", "", time()+3600*24);
```

Although it would be valid to create new cookies by appending (or embedding) an integer into a string you should avoid using square brackets.

C.